# Clean invalid characters from data held in a Spark RDD

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a PySpark RDD imported from JSON files.
The data elements contain a number of values that have characters that are not desirable.  For the sake of argument only those characters that are string.printable should be in those JSON files.

Given that there are a large number of elements that contain text information I have been trying to find a way of mapping the incoming RDD to a function to clean the data and returning a cleansed RDD as output.
I can find ways of printing a cleansed element from the RDD but not the entire collection of elements and returning then as an RDD.

An example document might be as show below and undesirable characters might creep into the userAgent, marketingReference and pageTags elements or indeed any of the text elements.

```
{
    "documentId": "abcdef12-1234-5678-fedc-cba9876543210",
    "documentType": "contentSummary",
    "dateTimeCreated": "2017-01-01T03:00:22.478Z"
    "body": {
        "requestUrl": "http://www.our-web-site.com/en-gb/line-of-business/product-category/irritating-guid/",
        "requestMethod": "GET",
        "responseCode": "200",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 etc",
        "requestHeaders": {
            "connection": "close",
            "host": "www.our-web-site.com",
            "accept-language": "en-gb",
            "via": "1.1 www.our-web-site.com",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 etc",
            "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
            "clientIp": "99.99.99.99",
            "referer": "http://www.our-web-site.com/en-gb/line-of-business/product-category/irritating-guid/",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "incap-client-ip": "99.99.99.99"
        },
        "body": {
            "pageId": "/content/our-web-site/en-gb/holidays/interstitial",
            "pageVersion": "1.0",

            "pageClassification": "product-page",
            "pageTags": "spark, python, rdd, other words",
            "MarketingReference": "BUYMEPLEASE",
            "referrer": "http://www.our-web-site.com/en-gb/line-of-business/product-category/irritating-guid/",
            "webSessionId": "abcdef12-1234-5678-fedc-cba9876543210"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample of RDD (e.g. using rdd.take(5))?

Comment: Sadly not due to data confidentiality.

Comment: Can you please share the format of the RDD, you can use "key1", "value1" ,etc instead of the real values. I'm interested in the structure of the data, not the actual content

Comment: I have added the JSON source for the RDD to the question.  userAgent, pageTags, MarketingReference and a plethora of other tags in the body suffer from undesirable characters.

All elements within body are in "key":"value" format, there is no further nesting.

The JSON documents are received from a source over which I have no control or influence.

Comment: What if you just clean raw data before turning them into an rdd ?

Comment: The problem is that there are millions of JSON files that are poorly validated prior to them being supplied to me.  I am looking for an *efficient* way of ingesting/cleansing them.

Comment: If this was the ideal world I'd simply refuse to process files of insufficient quality.  In reality the quality bar has been set rather low.
My input routine reads a batch of files into a list and then does a union.

```
rdd_list = [self._spark_context.textFile(file) for file in file_paths]
return self._spark_context.union(rdd_list)
```

Comment: @DavePoole you can do rdd = sparkContext.textFile(','.join(files)) instead of  doing union.

Comment: So you have say a directory fulled with json and you want to get an RDD which contains those jsons after removing bad characters?

Comment: How about using "RDD.filter(). refer : http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-filter-example/

Comment: What are the unwanted/undesirable characters?  How do you want those characters to be removed? Do you want to remove the whole JSON document and return an RDD containing filtered JSON documents or do you want to cleanse each field and return an RDD which contains all the JSON documents.

Comment: Unless you provide the data you're trying to process, nothing is going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was trying to clean up data downstream for which poor (or totally absent) data quality practices existed upstream.

Eventually it was accepted that we were attempting to address a symptom and not the cause.  The cost of retrospectively fixing data was proven to be massively more than the cost of handling data properly in the first place.

Comment: Very true, Dave. Data preparation in the very upstream steps ensure that one would have less problems in the the downstream systems.